# using webrtc for hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, webrtc, hybrid-mobile-app

We are working on an app Which requires Video Chat functionality. Is it possible to use hybrid and webrtc or any other lib to support IOS and Android?. 
I have seen a few post with similar queries but those are year an old so any new Update on it.

Comment: webrtc is for web, you can actually write clients in javascript and run them on the browsers of your intended target devices

Comment: can i use the same on cordova and build app compatible both on ios and android. see my end goal is mobile applications.

Comment: why not just build a responsive website its much easier

Comment: Do you know kurento?

Comment: Take a look at this thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kurento/bxYWJ0FT7-4  you will get all the info you need to write a android app client for Kurento webrtc server

Comment: i am checking kurento hope it works.Thanks

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview. WebRTC seems to be part of the latest webview for android. Latest in this case seems to be a not yet released version.

Answer (score 0):

I use the Cordova plugin iosrtc : https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc

If that can help you, I create a sample application that creates a webrtc call on iOS : https://github.com/apizee/ApiRTC-mobile

I will finish the android version soon.

Answer (score -1):

I used Skylink which is cross platform (iOS, Android and web), works well for me.

EDIT: As of 2020 I would explore more options.